# How the rotating coil produces zero induced emf on changing the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

[image]

since the rotating coil which produces the induced emf that varies sinusoidally the emf produced for one complete revolution of the coil is zero.
then for any number of rotation the induced emf should be zero only no then why they are calculating the emf induced

Comment: Emf is zero only twice in one full rotation, and only for a moment, see the sine curve.

Answer (score 2):

The question states that there is 'zero EMF' in a D.C motor. But there is indeed an EMF in the coil. Here is the reason for supporting my answer:

Because there is rotation of the coil in a D.C motor, there is obviously a torque.

So this torque acting on the coil rotates the coil as a result the axle connected to the coil starts rotating which completes the transfer of electrical energy into mechanical energy.

But when the coil rotates the number of magnetic field lines passing through the coil varies as a result, the magnetic flux associated with the coil changes.

We know that according to Maxwell’s Induction law, an EMF is induced in a coil whenever there is a change in the magnetic flux associated with the coil. The EMF induced in this way will always try to counteract the source which produced the change in magnetic flux.

So in the case of the DC motor, an EMF is induced on the coil, which tries to counteract the potential that is causing the current to flow through the coil. So this so-called EMF which tries to reduce the applied voltage in the coil is called the counter EMF or the Back EMF.

So yes, the EMF is just called Back EMF. But of course, there are exactly two points where the EMF of the coil is 0. Those are when the coil has completed 90-degree and 270-degree rotation respectively, because there is no current flowing through the coil, thus the potential difference is 0, and no counter EMF to it.

It is even shown in the sin wave itself:
[image]

Let the point of intersection of the x-axis and y-axis be O.

In the above image, there is an EMF at all the values between O and E0 and O and -E0.

Only at O, there is no EMF.

So it is interesting how your diagram itself contradicts yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The *mean* emf over a whole number of cycles is indeed zero. But the *instantaneous* emf, $\mathscr E(t)$, is zero only at two points in each cycle.

Suppose that we connect a resistor across the rotating coil (using slip-rings), so that the circuit resistance is $R$. The power, $P(t)$, dissipated at time $t$ is
$$P(t)=\frac 1R \mathscr E^2(t)=\frac 1R\mathscr E_0^2 \sin^2(\omega t)$$
$\sin^2(\omega t)$ is never negative throughout the cycle, so its mean value is positive. In fact its mean value is $\tfrac 12$. Therefore the energy dissipated in the resistance over a whole number of cycles is the same as if there were a constant power of $\frac 1R \frac 12 \mathscr E_0^2$, so a constant emf of $\frac{\mathscr E_0}{\sqrt 2}$. This is called the *root mean square* (rms) value of the emf. As we've seen, it has an important role, even though the mean emf may be zero.